# WebSocket within iframe sandbox fails on Firefox, but works on Edge/Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, websocket

The following code shows an `<iframe sandbox...` pointing to a page that opens a test websocket with a message on successful open. It works correctly on Chrome and Edge printing the `It worked!` message immediately.

On Firefox it fails with `Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure.` and no further reasoning.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <iframe
      sandbox="allow-scripts"
      src="https://firefox-wss-example.tiiny.site/"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

The linked websocket page source code is simply as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <script>
      const ws = new WebSocket('wss://demo.piesocket.com/v3/channel_1?notify_self');

      ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
        console.log('It worked!');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried a mixture of `wss://` and `ws://`, as well as permissive CORS headers, but none of my attempts fix the issue on Firefox despite having an appropriate setup. I am starting to think this is a Firefox 97 bug but am unsure of how to verify.

Why does this snippet work on most browsers but fails on Firefox?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue in latest Firefox, no reason for the error... Works fine in other browsers

Answer (score 1):

I've been through this before, spend weeks on investigations, what I found is: Firefox runs sandboxed JavaScript under the `blob://` protocol, [and you're only allowed to upgrade to WebSocket from `http://` and `https://` connections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism#upgrading_to_a_websocket_connection). `blob://` isn't either.

Although it's not very clear in their documentation, you may take a look into the [websocket upgrade implementation](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/dom/websocket/WebSocket.cpp) as well as in [this issue about CSP inheritance](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1570889) to understand it better, but it's basically the way Firefox have chosen to implement Sandboxing.

We never found a workaround for this, the only way was to drop the Sandboxing, or drop Firefox support for this specific feature.

On the other hand, Chromium based browsers saves the script file locally (I cannot say with 100% of confidence if it is stored in a temporary directory or virtual file system), and still uses the `http://` protocol to access them, this way you can upgrade to `ws://` or `wss://`. Those browsers may also inherit CSP, since they keeps the *opener* instance.

Edit: This problem is not tied to an specific Firefox version, it has been implemented this way for a long time. I has been 5 or 6 releases from the time I went into this problem, it still this way, and will probably stay this way, it's not considered a bug and it's not close to a highly requested *feature*.

Comment: I was having the same issue, using a local file to open the iframe, it worked on chrome but failed on firefox. I noticed that Firefox wasn't sending the cookies to the websocket can establish the connection. I moved to test the same file from a "LiveServer" (http server in localhost) and it worked.